# How many whole bricks 6 × 12 × 24 cm3 will be sufficient to construct a solid cube of minimum size

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

How many whole bricks 6 × 12 × 24 cm3 will be sufficient to construct a solid cube of minimum size

I dont know how to tackle this minimum size condition . Can someone explain this part and solve the question

Comment: The largest dimension of the brick is 24 centimeters, so the brick will overflow any cube with a side shorter than 24 cm (we can safely ignore the possibilitiy of placing bricks diagonally). Can you do 24? Hint: 6 and 12 are factors of 24. Use lego models, if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each brick has a longest dimension of $24$ cm, you can’t possibly make a cube with a side any shorter than $24$ cm. A cube with side $24$ cm has a volume of $24^3=13824\text{ cm}^3$, and each brick has a volume of $6\cdot12\cdot24=1728\text{ cm}^3$. Now $\frac{13824}{1728}=8$; is it possible to stack $8$ of these bricks to form a cube?

Comment: I saw this solution somewhere  Size of each cube = 6 cm
So number of blocks = (6 * 12 * 24)/(6*6*6) = 8 

How they came up with size of each cube to be 6 cm

Comment: Secondly your answer is perfect Brian . Thank You

Comment: @mark: You’re welcome. What they seem to be doing is noticing that a $6\times12\times24$ brick can be cut into eight $6\times6\times6$ cubes, but it’s a coincidence that the answer to the question is also $8$. It works out because a $24\times24\times24$ cube can be cut into $4\times4\times4=64$ of the side $6$ cubes, so there’s just enough volume for $64/8=8$ of the bricks, **provided** that they can be arranged to fit — which of course they can.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the units of measure used make no difference, so here it is natural to use $6\,$cm as unit of measure, and the bricks have dimensions $1\times2\times4$. I think you can see how to put these together to first form a $1\times4\times4$ "plane", and then stack those to a $4\times4\times4$ block.

However no limitation of construction techniques was imposed (stacking is just one of them), and the question was to find the minimum number of bricks used. Supposing you don't consider using $0$ bricks to form a $0\times0\times0$ "cube" an acceptable solution, I would then take a single brick (which would be the answer to the question), chop it into two $1\times2\times2$ pieces and stack those to a $2\times2\times2$ cube.

Comment: +1 My favorite puzzle (IMO-training level in difficulty) in the use of 2x2x1 bricks is the following. You are given a set of 2000 2x2x1 bricks. You can obviously build a 20x20x20 cube out of these in many ways. Prove that no matter how you build the large cube, you can "push a line" through the cube in such a way that the line is not blocked by any of the bricks.